# SQL query table mapping many to one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

```
Table 1 (P_Data)                                      Table 2 (Address)
| Data_Id | First_Name  | Last_Name |                 | ID | Data_Id  | Address_Type | address_data|
|---------|-------------|-----------|                 |----|----------|--------------|-------------|
| 1       | John        | Page      |                 | 1  | 1        | Residential  | address1    | 
| 2       | Bob         | Builder   |                 | 2  | 1        | Bill_To      | address2    |
                                                      | 3  | 2        | Residential  | address3    | 
                                                      | 4  | 2        | Bill_To      | address4    |
```

I want an output with only 2 fields but it must contain all the addresses (either 1 or many or none) for each id belonging to P_Data table.

Maybe like

```
| Data_Id | First_Name  | Last_Name |  Address_Type | address_Data |                                                
|---------|-------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|
| 1       | John        | Page      | Residential   | address1     |
|         |             |           | Bill_To       | address2     |              
| 2       | Bob         | Builder   | Residential   | address3     |
|         |             |           | Bill_To       | address4     |
```

Is it even possible? Or something which won't repeat the Data_Id field but will also give all the Address fields.

Note: The address fields can be none to 10 for one Data_Id. Looking for a generalised query.

**EDIT:**
I tried this

```
SELECT pd.Data_Id, pd.First_Name, pd.Last_Name, a.Address_Type, a.address_data 
from P_Data as pd 
JOIN Address as a ON pd.Data_Id = a.Data_Id
```

got this as output

```
| Data_Id | First_Name  | Last_Name |  Address_Type | address_Data |                                                
|---------|-------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|
| 1       | John        | Page      | Residential   | address1     |
| 1       | John        | Page      | Bill_To       | address2     |              
| 2       | Bob         | Builder   | Residential   | address3     |
| 2       | Bob         | Builder   | Bill_To       | address4     |
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: And what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov the server is client side, so not very sure about it. But it was setuped in the year 2016

Comment: What you are seeking is a report, not a query result. SQL will repeat values where it is needed so that you can (for example) sort on each column, or extract any row(s) from the result and have values in each column. SQL is NOT a report writer.

Comment: `select @@version`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 and later you can use `lag`.

```
SELECT nullif(pd.Data_Id, lag(pd.Data_Id, 1, null) over (order by pd.Data_Id)) as Data_Id,
  nullif(pd.First_Name, lag(pd.First_Name, 1, null) over (order by pd.Data_Id)) as First_Name,
  nullif(pd.Last_Name, lag(pd.Last_Name, 1, null) over (order by pd.Data_Id)) as Last_Name,
  a.Address_Type, a.address_data 
from P_Data as pd 
JOIN Address as a ON pd.Data_Id = a.Data_Id
ORDER BY pd.Data_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`, set columns to `NULL` and carefully sort the results:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by t1.Data_Id order by t2.id) = 1
             then t1.data_id
        end) as data_id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by t1.Data_Id order by t2.id) = 1
             then t1.First_Name
        end) as First_Name,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by t1.Data_Id order by t2.id) = 1
             then t1.Last_Name
        end) as Last_Name,
       t2.Address_Type, t2.address_Data
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.Data_Id = t1.Data_Id
order by t1.Data_Id, t2.id;
```

Note that this type of transformation is usually better done at the application layer.